# Data not saved properly into XML file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am trying to save data to a XML file.

```
if (isset( $_POST['submit'])) { 

   $name =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);


   $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
   $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
   $xml->load('/var/www/Report/file.xml');

   $element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('entries');
   $newItem = $xml->createElement('reports');

   $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('timestamp', date("F j, Y, g:i a",time())));
   $newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('name', $name));
   $element -> item(0) -> appendChild($newItem);    

   $xml->formatOutput = true; // this adds spaces, new lines and makes the XML more readable format.
   $xmlString = $xml->saveXML(); // $xmlString contains the entire String
   $xml->save('/var/www/Report/file.xml');

}
```

Anytime I use mysql_real_escape_string() to  escapes special characters in my string or  try to to sanitize my data, my XML file looks like something in the image below.

[image]

I don't understand why the name start tag is missing in my XML file and why my data $name isn't saved into the XML file either. How could I to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Firefox does not show the xml byte-by-byte, rather it formats it itself. Therefore empty elements appear with only one self closing tag, no matter how they appear in the xml source. If you want to see the exact xml output, then open it in a text editor.

2) **mysql_real_escape_string** escapes characters that are problematic for mysql, not for XML: for example it does not escape '<'. Instead it, you should use **DOMDocument::createTextNode**. So instead of

```
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('name', $name));
```

use

```
$nameElement = $xml->createElement('name');
$nameElement->appendChild( $xml->createTextNode($name) );
$newItem->appendChild($nameElement);
```

3) As you see, the `$name` is empty, but I don't know what can be the problem with your POST data seeing only this code, maybe there is no `<input name='name' />` in your form: I sometimes accidentally set an **id** attribute to inputs instead of the **name** attribute.

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer @tzunghaor . Now the XML tags are been fully created even if there is no data to put in them. So is there a way to escape jargons from user input before saving the data into a XML file ?

Comment: What do you mean by jargon? Vulgar words? Parsing human language is quite a challenge.

Comment: Oh what I meant was like special character a user might put in as a input into the web form. I wouldn't want to save those kind of data into the XML file. ie **‘,/,:,“ ** . Is there a way to clean up the user inputs?

Comment: You can use strtr($input, array(";" => "", "," => "", ...));

Comment: You're brilliant like. Thanks for everything. I'd actually buy you coffee if I could. You were very helpful.